# Facebook API Integration and extended access token time for a WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Ultimately I'm building a site for my church and they have a Facebook account or 2, done pages and groups, and I'd like to be able to access all those to get their feeds and post to them etc from the site so I believe I need access tokens for all those. I just don't know where to start.

---

Ok so I'm starting to get lost in all this authentication stuff. I've read that

- To do things on behalf of a user, you need an access token for that user and
- To do things on behalf of a page or an app, access tokens for those,
  and so on.
- You also need to have an app registered that apparently can't allow API access from two or more domains that are
  different.

I'm getting lost on how to structure an application to do what I want it to do because the documentation is scattered. I want to make a WordPress plugin that allows me to be able link to any relevant pages, user accounts, apps, etc that my client might own and be able to make API calls on their behalf.

*How do I set up such an app? How do I handle OAuth elegantly etc?*

So far I pretty much just write a class that stores an App ID, etc and persisted the access token for I guess what ever user was logged in when they went through the OAuth process and the class checks for expiry of that token.

Could some of you more seasoned Facebook developers out there help me get started on maybe a relatively standard of going about creating an application like this? Please don't just send me to a Facebook documentation page without directing me on how to use that info. I've read a lot of it already and it's helpful but kinda patchy. I'd like this WordPress plugin to be relatively universal, so I can drop it into other WordPress installs and hook into whatever Facebook accounts, pages, groups and other places that I need to.

Comment: read the FB Documentation before asking

Comment: Remove downvotes if you just placed them. I redirected this user from #facebook IRC. You can read the logs here if you want http://phwdbot.iriscouch.com/irc/_design/viewer/index.html

Comment: @ShivanRaptor The Facebook documentation doesn't state how to do this. It tells you how to handle authentication but not in this format. He needs extended access tokens for various accounts while placing it in a single plugin. It's quite a unique situation.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta The paragraphs have been fixed.

Comment: @phwd I believe he should use single Facebook account. One single account is already sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a one-off WordPress plugin for your own use, you can skip through the oauth authentication stuff and just generate an access_token using the Graph Explorer tool (grant the relevant permissions for posting to pages etc): https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

Or generate an App Access Token by following the instructions here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-app-tokens/

Making it generic will require setting up configurable Plugins using the WordPress documentation as a starting point, and then hooking in the Facebook API. Two ways you can go about it:

- Let the user enter their App ID, App Secret and other App info from Facebook and authenticate them via the Plugin, or
- Let the user generate an access token themselves and let them enter it into the WP Plugin on the settings page.

The process of going about creating a WordPress plugin and posting / getting stuff from Facebook is too complicated to explain here. You will have to use the documentation from WordPress and Facebook to accomplish this (whether you like it or not).

There are already existing plugins that can handle the authentication process for you, I would start there. Extend the existing plugins to then do what you want or create a new plugin that builds on the authentication plugin. It will save you quite a bit of work in the end.

Comment: Ok thanks for all the info so far, but for clarity, will an app access token allow me to get/post things on behalf of not just the app itself, but the user that owns the FB acct the app is on and pages, etc the user owns as well? This is where I thought I needed multiple access tokens after reading the FB docs. Also, @Niraj Shah, could you make a mention of these FB plugins that already handle the authentication? I looked around for WP plugins for FB integration but was finding a lot that didn't do hardly anything (ie just a Like btn) or they were severely outdated and no longer worked.

Comment: For WP Plugins, I use the FB Connect one at http://www.sociable.es/facebook-connect/. You can use a App Access token to publish information only. You will need the User's access token if you want to read and write messages, and you will need to request the `manage_pages` permission to post as Admin. The following WP Plugin works well for publishing to Pages: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/facebook-page-publish/